# MySQL - how to find similar data in two mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two table like this :

### table1

```
| cat   | id   | 
|-----  |------|
| 110** |  12  | 
| 110** |  18  |  
| 110** |  13  |
----------------
```

### table2

```
| cat   | qty  | 
|-----  |------|
| 11012 |  2   | 
| 11017 |  8   |  
| 11016 |  1   |
----------------
```

### result

```
| cat   | 
|-----  |
| 11012 | 
---------
```

can I combine cat,id columns in table1 (like 11012) to get the same value in cat column in table2 (like 11012)?
I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT a.cat,a.id FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.cat LIKE CONCAT('%', b.cat, '%')
```

but I didn't get the results I expected.

Comment: Show desired output/

Comment: WHY do you have those ** in the cat table in the first place? It seems that the entire table structure is completely wrong

Comment: @YourCommonSense I only get it from companies that are my clients. maybe for them it is secret. If the data they provide is so, can I say that their table structure is completely wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '*' FROM t1.cat), id) = t2.cat
```

Logic: remove trailing asterisks from `cat`, concatenate `id`, then compare.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e74d034115b3094c93b2a94e1000f50)

Comment: i have tried, but how to validate the value? I want only 11012 to show up. with the query you provided 11018 and 11013 also appear. where as in table2 there are no values ​​of 11018 and 11013

Comment: @Mr.Coolhead I don't believe you. Fiddle added - look at.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. i forget repair my table2 data. Thanks for your help! u save my day!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand question correctly, you should do

```
SELECT a.cat,a.id FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON LEFT(a.cat,3) = LEFT(b.cat, 3)
```

Comment: I have fixed my table. I want to get results like in the results table. is there a way to concatenate the cat, id column in table1 (replace '**' with the value in the id column)?